# Get instance parent property accessor chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, parent, chaining, accessor

I have reason to believe what I want is possible, but I'm not articulating correctly, and having trouble searching for it.  What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

Imagine I have a generic Object `obj` like so:

```
const obj={
  job:function(){},
  age:function(){},
  school:function(){}
}
```

I want to be able to call it as chained list of object properties with variable length and then access that chain within a final method.  Some examples:

js

```
obj.job.school.age.job.school() // in the school body, I should know  'job.school.age.job' and that I am `school`
obj.job.school() // in the school body, I should know 'job' and that I am `school`
obj.job.job.job() // in the job body, I should know 'job.job' and that I am `job`
```

The formatting doesn't matter.  It doesn't have to be a string.  The main point is that within the final method, I should know the property chain that got to me on this instance.  A property should be able to be chained as a function or as a plain property.

The way I see it, there are two problems to solve.  The first is the chaining part.  I think I solved that part with:
js

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.job,obj)
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.school,obj)
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj.age,obj)
```

That makes the object dynamically chainable at every key.  So, for example it allows for:

```
obj.job.job.school.job.age.age.school.job.school.age.age.job()
```

But I'm stuck on the second part.  That is to know how we got to where we are inside of the method body.  So that in the above, the final `job` method, should know that it is `job` and on this instance the properties that preceeded it were: `job.job.school.job.age.age.school.job.school.age.age`.

I hope this isn't too muddled.  I'll edit if anything is unclear.

Comment: try this `const obj={
  job:function(){ return this },
  age:function(){ return this },
  school:function(){ return this }
}`

Comment: What do you mean by "the `job` method should *know*"? Do you want it to be able to get, for example, a string describing the chain of properties before it: "job.job.school.job.age.age.school.job.school.age.age"?

Comment: @MikeM yup - you got it just right

Answer (score 0):

Chaining isn't magic. When you say

```
a.b.c()
```

it's really the same as

```js
let x = a.b
x.c()
```

So in your case, `obj` has 3 keys in it each being a function. If each function returns `this` then you can chain them, but you also have to call the function - not just give its key:

```js
const obj={
  job: () => {/* do something */ return obj},
  age: () => {/* do something */ return obj},
  school: () => {/* do something */ return obj}
}

// you can now chain them because each returns 'obj'
obj.job().job().school().job().age().age().school().job().school().age().age().job();

// but doing this won't work since obj.job returns the job function itself, not obj
obj.job.job();
// gives: Uncaught TypeError: obj.job.job is not a function
```

Comment: I'm with you.  This was my understanding as well.  But I believe there is a way to do what I want to do using advanced Object methods / Proxy, or something like that.  Certainly the arrow function is easier than using `setPrototypeOf` when I call a function, but if I pass a property, as you stated, it won't work.

Comment: when you say 'obj.job.job()` do you expect it to call the `job` function twice?

Comment: No - from within the final `job` method body, I want  to know that `obj.job.job` is the property chain that has been invoked to get here.

Comment: The above example will not work with arrow functions, if executed on a web browser, try changing them to normal functions. because this will return window object in case of arrow functions.

Comment: right @JayantMalik - I changed it to return `obj` instead

Comment: saying `obj.job.job` seems confusing and non-intuitive. `obj.job` is a function, but you want it to also be and object with functions. Overloading the purpose like this seems like a bad idea

Comment: usually you use `setPrototypeOf` to force an object to be viewed as another type similar to class extension. Here you are saying `obj.job` is an `obj`, but is that true? is the `job` function an instance of `obj` and what does that mean?

Comment: I don't know that `setPrototypeOf` is the best solution - it's just the best I've come up with.  Also, I'm not arguing whether this is a good or bad idea.  I just want to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem, it seems like you want to keep track of function calls along with implementing chaining. Here is a possible solution to your problem. Maybe it can be improved but it will provide you basic idea.

#### Problem 01:

We need chaining behaviour, so here is how we do it.

```js
const email_validator = {
    tld: function(){ return this;},
    min: function(length){ return this;},
    max: function(length){ return this; }
}
```

> Make sure to use regular functions, because they will work as expected, arrow functions will cause issues in case of web browsers.

#### Problem 02

Keep track of our chain.

```js
const email_validator = {
    // Regular functions
    tld: function(){ this.addToStack(this.tld); return this;},
    min: function(length){ this.addToStack(this.min); return this;},
    max: function(length){ this.addToStack(this.max); return this; },

    // We will keep track of chain.
    stack: [],

    // The function needs to be after each function call.
    addToStack: function(func){ this.stack.push(func); }
}
```

The above code will store each function call in an array, Just make sure to call `addToStack` function after every function, before returning this.

> You can pass string instead of function, if you want to keep track of strings, instead of functions. Or change it as per your need.

I hope the above provides you some idea of how to do it.

### Usage

Here is how to use the above code:

```js
const email_validator = {
    // Regular functions
    tld: function(){ this.addToStack(this.tld); return this;},
    min: function(length){ this.addToStack(this.min); return this;},
    max: function(length){ this.addToStack(this.max); return this; },

    // We will keep track of chain.
    stack: [],

    // The function needs to be after each function call.
    addToStack: function(func){ this.stack.push(func); }
}

// This will contain stack of functions.
const history = email_validator.tld().tld().max().tld().stack;

// Print in format: tld.tld.max
const message = history.map(item => item.name).join(".");
console.log(message); // tld.tld.max
```

Comment: This has some promise, but still within `tld` it doesn't know how it got there.  So I can't for instance say, `email_validator.tld.tld.max.tld()` and know what the chain is from within the final method body.

Comment: You are trying to access `email_validator.tld` as a property but rather it should be accessed as a function, because email_validator.tld is reference to function rather than parent object denoted using this.

Comment: You should  read my question.  I believe what I want is available via Object.reflection in ES6+, but I don't know how.

Comment: I am not able to understand what exactly you mean? Can you provide example using Object.reflection

Comment: If I could provide an example, I wouldn’t’ have asked the question

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but I feel like this deserves an answer - does this accomplish what you were trying to do?:

```
function the_obj() {
  console.log(...arguments)
  console.log(the_obj.accessStack)
  the_obj.accessStack.splice(0, the_obj.accessStack.length)
}
the_obj.accessStack = []

Object.defineProperty(the_obj, 'job', {
  get: function() {
    the_obj.accessStack.push('job')
    return the_obj
  },
})

Object.defineProperty(the_obj, 'school', {
  get: function() {
    the_obj.accessStack.push('school')
    return the_obj
  },
})

Object.defineProperty(the_obj, 'age', {
  get: function() {
    the_obj.accessStack.push('age')
    return the_obj
  },
}) 
   
the_obj.job.school.age.job.school() // ['job', 'school', 'age', 'job', 'school']
```